# Kendo Window showing cross in title bar...only on my computer

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

[image: Cross in upper left hand corner of Kendo window]

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC app and using the Kendo Window control for popups in an iFrame. For some reason, I am getting a tiny cross in the leftmost part of the title bar. This is only happening on IE 11 and Chrome. The cross does not appear on Firefox. (I'm not worried about Chrome, as this app is intended to run only on IE 11.)

It appears to be something unique to my computer, as I have tried it on other computers with IE 11 and the cross does not appear.

I believe the Kendo controls show this character when it doesn't have data of some sort (I've seen Kendo dropdowns briefly show this same symbol while debugging), but I have no idea what data it's missing.

This may be a related problem, so I'll throw this out there: certain Unicode HTML characters like & #raquo; ( » ) show up as weird boxes with characters. Again, this is on IE -- and only on my computer. I dug down a bit in the MVC code and it seemed to be related to Bootstrap (I can get & #raquo; to properly show up if I'm not using the Bootstrap theme).

I tried replacing all my Windows fonts with the fonts from a known 'working' computer, but it didn't change anything.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. bootstrap.css was using Helvetica as one of its fonts:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

My computer doesn't have Helvetica Neue, so it fell through to Helvetica. Something about that font doesn't want to render Unicode characters in IE 11. Once I removed the Helvetica option and IE fell through to Arial, the weird character was gone.

Comment: Hi dev5000, welcome to StackOverflow.  In the future, please include a code snippet so we can diagnose the issue.  The list of applied CSS styles and the relevant HTML would have worked in this situation.